# change javafx webview orientation on button click

Tags: java, javafx

i'm trying to make a java program.users choose their html file and it will be showed in a javafx webview(or another web browser inside program).
i'd like to add a button for toggle webview orientation from horizontal to vertical or vise versa that users can check their html file if it is responsive.
i'm not sure if i can resize current scene or i can `setScene` between  2 scene or deleting and newing scene...

```
VBox root = new VBox();
VBox root1 = new VBox();

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 500);
Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1, 500, 900);
```

thanks and sorry for bad English grammar!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how you can dynamically change size:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageTest extends Application{

    private static final double WIDTH = 900, HEIGHT = 500;
    private Stage stage;
    private VBox root;
    boolean isVertical = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setTitle("Dynamic Stage Resize");

        root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        root.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Button addNode = new Button("Change Size");
        addNode.setOnAction( e -> changeSize());
        root.getChildren().add(addNode);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    void changeSize() {

        if(isVertical) {
            root.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        } else {
            root.setPrefSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        }

        isVertical = !isVertical;
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```